# Lentitud en el simulador con Xcode 8

Tags: xcode

Desde que actualice a Xcode 8 ,estoy experimentando mucha lentitud en el simulador ,concretamente al introducir texto en un Text Field ,tarda varios segundos en aparecer las letras tecleadas.Con la version 7.3 iba perfecto.¿A alguien mas le pasa?

Answer (score 1):

Al actualizar a XCode 8 se puede experimentar una lentitud ya que requiere mas recursos que versiones anteriores, yo he experimentado lo mismo cuando uso el Interface Builder.

De hecho si revisas los requerimientos, el mismo macOS El Capitan requiere mas recursos que sus antecesores:

> Xcode 8 requires a Mac running macOS El Capitan version 10.11.4 or
>   later. It includes SDKs for iOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, macOS Sierra
>   version 10.12, and tvOS 10.0.

Comment: Lo podria entender si usara el simulador del iphone 7 o si la nueva version incorporara nuevas funcionalidades que requieran mas capacidad de proceso,pero por lo poco que he visto ,mayoritariamente son cambios de nomenclatura,el resto es practicamente igual.

Answer (score 0):

si usas un HD te recomiendo cambiar por un SSD...

yo tenía un problema parecido pero era mas general, colocar botones, WebViews, TextFields, hasta Labels, pero solo cambié el disco duro HD 500gb por un SSD, sacrifique 250 gb, pero vale la pena, cuando iniciaba el simulador tardaba mas de 1 minuto, esto en caso que tu mac este usando un HD, de lo contrario es raro que te de esos problemas,